# Книги по Python + QT

Tags: python, qt, книги

Что можно почитать русского о Python + QT? Желательно о PySide. И еще вопрос: есть ли существенные отличия между PyQT и PySide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По PyQt есть книга Прохоренка. По PySide не встречал.

Comment: А есть какие-либо принципиальные отличия PyQT и PySide?

Comment: Если честно, я с QtSide дела не имел, поэтому сказать компетентно не могу.

Comment: Пару лет назад когда я щупал PySide в нем иногда чего то нахватало. Но это может быть была моя криворукость, ИМХО если знаете Qt то хоть PySide, хоть PyQt...

Comment: я писал и на том и на другом. Различие сводится к from PyQt4 import и from PySide import. всё.